# postMessage error when using Youtube iframe API

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Seems that Youtube iframe API has recently introduced a bug in their iframe API.

This is an example of the error, extracted directly from the [Youtube iframe demo page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo):

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://google-developers.appspot.com').
g.C @ www-widgetapi.js:116
g.G @ www-widgetapi.js:113
setInterval (async)
ab @ www-widgetapi.js:89
kb @ www-widgetapi.js:114
W @ www-widgetapi.js:98
Y @ www-widgetapi.js:118
createYTPlayer @ as3_demo_functions.js:385
onYouTubePlayerAPIReady @ as3_demo_functions.js:424
(anonymous) @ www-widgetapi.js:140
(anonymous) @ www-widgetapi.js:140
10:33:24.521
```

Any idea how to fix this? Supposedly setting `origin` should prevent this from happening but seems that they're not using `origin` properly in their JS.